# Suppress page number for \part in ToC (memoir)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

Consider this MWE.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
\part{First Part}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\part{Second Part}
\chapter{Three}
\lipsum
\chapter{Four}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How to suppress the page number for parts in the ToC? I tried to use `tocstyle` but got error messages instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memoir` provides the command `\cftpagenumbersoff{...}`:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{palatino}

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}% <- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
\part{First Part}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\part{Second Part}
\chapter{Three}
\lipsum
\chapter{Four}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]